# Laravel eloquent relationship between two many to many related tables

Tags: laravel

I have many to many related two tables, "roles" and "users" with pivot table as "user_roles".

In Role model

**$this->belongsToMany('users', 'user_roles');**

In User model

**$this->belongsToMany('roles', 'user_roles');**

Is this a valid relation?

Answer (score 0):

You want a pivot table and a many to many relationship using a pivot table like you said.

What you are trying to do is explained in [Laravel documentation - Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

No. The first parameter should be the class name of the related model:

```
$this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_roles');

$this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles');
```

Otherwise you should be fine if you foreign keys follow the convention...

[See the documentation for more info](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: Unless you are using custom names on your pivot table you really only need to declare your model name when creating your relationship s. Like  $this->belongsToMany('Role');

Comment: Well `user_roles` *is* a custom name. Default would be `role_user`